# Call a DataStore inside an interceptor

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to call a method from the datastore with flow inside an interceptor, but it doesn't work.

What is the correct way to do it?

Here I define my interceptor

```kotlin
class AuthorizationInterceptor @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val appContext: Context,
) : HttpInterceptor {

    private val authPreferences = AuthPreferences(appContext)

    override suspend fun intercept(
        request: HttpRequest,
        chain: HttpInterceptorChain
    ): HttpResponse {
        // here I try to get the token
        var tokenString = "";
        authPreferences.getAccessToken.collect { token ->
            tokenString = token
        }
        return chain.proceed(request.withHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $tokenString"))

        //return chain.proceed(request.withHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 1111"))
    }

}
```

Here I define my Store

```kotlin
private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore("auth_pref");

class AuthPreferences(private val context: Context) {

    companion object {
        val AUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN = stringPreferencesKey(name = "auth_access_token")
        val AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN = stringPreferencesKey(name = "auth_refresh_token")
    }

    suspend fun saveAccessToken(token: String) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[AUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN] = token
        }
    }

    val getAccessToken: Flow<String> = context.dataStore.data
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[AUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN] ?: ""
        }

    suspend fun saveRefreshToken(token: String) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN] = token
        }
    }

    val getRefreshToken: Flow<String> = context.dataStore.data
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN] ?: ""
        }
}
```

I think my problem is with flows

Comment: This has nothing to do with jetpack compose. Use runBlocking and then call first on the flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it same that
val getRefreshToken =runBlocking { session.getRefreshToken() }

and after that you can use it.